# finding email addresses in python with regex

Tags: python, regex

Hi I'm trying to find a list of e-mails from a website. there is 4 e-mail addresses on the website but only returns 2 emails.

I'm using this to help search for the emails.

```
emails = re.findall(r'[^\s@<>]+@[^\s@<>]+\.[^\s@<>]+',s)
        print(count, ' email address found : ',item)
        count += 1
```

Comment: Can you add the emails this does not capture to your question so we can help you modify the expression?

Comment: Hard to tell when we don't know how the found and not found email adresses look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this regex :

```
regex = r"([\w\.-]+)@([\w\.-]+)(\.[\w\.]+)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern should match most forms of email addresses:

```
emails = re.findall(r'^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@(([0-9a-zA-Z])+([-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$',s)
```